# don't show category in Magento without image

Tags: php, image, magento

I'm trying to get this script NOT to display anything IF there is no image. Here's the script:

```
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_categories as $_category): 
    if (!$_category->getIsActive()): continue; endif;
    $cur_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
    $imageUrl = $cur_category->getImageUrl();
    if (empty($imageUrl)): $imageUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/np_thumb2.gif'; endif;
?>
```

Right now unless there is an image it will display a no-image image. I've been trying many things but everything I tried so far ends up giving a broken link. I'm sure it's easy, kinda like brain surgery, easy if you know how. All you need is a putty knife.

Thanks

Comment: Nice brain surgery analogy, LOL ;) Not familiar with Magento, but I think you should add a conditional statement to the template: if image is "no image", in your case np_thumb2.gif then do not render the image tag at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it should be something like this:

```
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_categories as $_category): 
if (!$_category->getIsActive()): continue; endif;
$cur_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
$imageUrl = $cur_category->getImageUrl();
if (empty($imageUrl)): 
//do nothing 
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. I had to add this to the top and bottom of the file:<?php if (!empty($imageUrl)): ?>code here...<?php endif; ?> Thank you